# SharePoint 2013 - jQuery on GridView

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to apply jQuery to the GridView to prevent fields from being edited and add some style/spacing to the form.  I already have the jquery added to the page and when someone views the list the style is there.  But as soon as they click on Edit the jQuery is ignored.

I figured some of the calls have changed, but even if I add the jQuery to the different fields it still does not apply.

Am I missing something/over thinking it?  and thoughts on locking fields in edit view?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without JQuery by using EditItemTemplate and Eval attribute.